# request_mem_region fails on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, gpio, device-tree

The call to `request_mem_region` is failing (returns `null`).
I would say that the memory region I'm trying to access (GPIO starting at `0x3f20000`) is being used.

I removed (`rmmod`) the module `bcm28795_gpio` but the request is still failing.
The modules I have loaded are (`lsmod`):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              427817  0 
rfkill                 16018  1 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            20511  0 
snd_pcm                75890  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              19160  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51908  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0 
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 5859  0 
ipv6                  347473  30`
```

`cat /proc/iomem` is returning the following:

```
00000000-3affffff : System RAM
  00008000-007e7483 : Kernel code
  00860000-0098e1ab : Kernel data
3f006000-3f006fff : dwc_otg
3f007000-3f007eff : /soc/dma@7e007000
3f00b840-3f00b84e : /soc/vchiq
3f00b880-3f00b8bf : /soc/mailbox@7e00b800
3f200000-3f2000b3 : /soc/gpio@7e200000
3f201000-3f201fff : /soc/uart@7e201000
  3f201000-3f201fff : /soc/uart@7e201000
3f202000-3f2020ff : /soc/sdhost@7e202000
3f980000-3f98ffff : dwc_otg`
```

I think this issue is related to the Device Tree, but I'm not sure what do next.

The driver code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_address.h>

#define DRIVER_NAME "tsgpio"

struct tsgpio_dev {
    struct resource res;
    void __iomem *virtbase;
} dev;

static const struct file_operations tsgpio_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
};

static struct miscdevice tsgpio_misc_device = {
    .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name = DRIVER_NAME,
    .fops = &tsgpio_fops,
};

static const struct of_device_id tsgpio_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-gpiomem" },
    {},
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, tsgpio_of_match);

int __init tsgpio_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    int ret;

    ret = misc_register(&tsgpio_misc_device);
    if (ret)
        return ENODEV;

    // Find address range in device tree
    ret = of_address_to_resource(pdev->dev.of_node, 0, &dev.res);

    if (ret) {
        ret = ENOENT;
        goto out_deregister;
    }

    // Request access to memory
    if (request_mem_region(dev.res.start, resource_size(&dev.res),
                                                    DRIVER_NAME) == NULL) {
        ret = EBUSY;
        goto out_deregister;
    }

    /* Arrange access to our registers (calls ioremap) */
    dev.virtbase = of_iomap(pdev->dev.of_node, 0);

    if (dev.virtbase == NULL) {
        ret = ENOMEM;
        goto out_release_mem_region;
        }

    return 0;

out_release_mem_region:
    release_mem_region(dev.res.start, resource_size(&dev.res));

out_deregister:
    misc_deregister(&tsgpio_misc_device);
    return ret;
}

int tsgpio_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    iounmap(dev.virtbase);
    release_mem_region(dev.res.start, resource_size(&dev.res));
    misc_deregister(&tsgpio_misc_device);
    return 0;
}

static struct platform_driver tsgpio_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = DRIVER_NAME,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(tsgpio_of_match),
    },
    .remove = __exit_p(tsgpio_remove),
};

static int __init tsgpio_init(void)
{
    return platform_driver_probe(&tsgpio_driver, tsgpio_probe);
}

static void __exit tsgpio_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&tsgpio_driver);
}

module_init(tsgpio_init);
module_exit(tsgpio_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Emanuel Oliveira");
```

Output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 1745.126636] tsgpio: init
[ 1745.130025] tsgpio: probe of 3f200000.gpiomem failed with error 16
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is failing because there is a mistake in your program, which you have not posted any lines from.

Comment: stark's comment addressed - code added.

Comment: You aren't checking the return from misc_register

Comment: code updated - misc_register is being checked now. No issues there.

Comment: It means you should go through the gpio driver. However, you can also ignore it and use the memory anyway. Resources use the honor system.

Comment: Beware that Broadcom is sloppy with the term *"GPIO"* compared to the usage by other SoCs and Linux.  Broadcom uses the single term *"GPIO"*, whereas others separate pin control functionality (e.g what Broadcom calls alternate pin functionality)(aka multiplexing pins) from general purpose I/O pin usage.  So your driver would interfere with the [pinctrl subsystem](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/pinctrl.txt?v=4.6), and could make the system unstable if you followed the bad advice of using this memory region without owning it.  IOW what you're trying to do is a bad idea.